# Use array data in each loop jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

This is my array and each loop. I want to look for each `input` field with a specific class and set its value. Can you guys see why this isnt working?

```
var inputTextIDs = [
  [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"],
  ["#agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName", "Location"]

 ];

$.each(inputTextIDs,function(i,v){
     $('input'+inputTextIDs[i]).val(inputTextIDs[v]);
});
```

Comment: here v is not a index.It is element at ith position.

Comment: Use inputids[i][0] as selector and inputids[i][1] as value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/sae7mv3e/

```js
var inputTextIDs = [
  [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"],
  ["#agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName", "Location"]

 ];
 


$.each(inputTextIDs,function(i,v){
  $('input'+inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(inputTextIDs[i][1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="hotelLocaiton" />
<input type="text" id="agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName" />
```

Since it's a **2 dimensional array**, where as you are providing only 1 dimension as **i**.

To **access 2D array**, you need to do something like **inputTextID[i][0]**

Comment: OMG! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In $.each(inputTextIDs,function(i,v){, 'i' is index and 'v' is value. So, i will be 0,1,2 and v will be equal to values in the array. Here in your case you have arrays in a big array. So, inputTextIDs[0] will get the first array in big array i.e. [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"], then inputTextIDs[0][0] will get first value in this array i.e. '.hotelLocation' and inputTextIDs[0][1] will get 'Location'.

So, following code will work:

```
var inputTextIDs = [
  [".hotelLocaiton", "Location"],
  ["#agentTransfersSearchForm_filter_transfersName", "Location"]

 ];

$.each(inputTextIDs,function(i,v){
     $('input'+inputTextIDs[i][0]).val(inputTextIDs[i][1]);
});
```